# Can access Apache virtual hosts through IE, but not Firefox or Chrome

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp, virtualhost, wampserver

After setting up WAMPserver, my Apache localhost site loads correctly on IE, Chrome, and Firefox.  However, after creating a virtual host (in this case, *bssb.dev*) Chrome and Firefox fail to retrieve the page (errors shown below).  However, IE successfully loads. Even after creation of the virtual host, all three browsers still successfully load localhost.

```
Chrome Error: This site can’t be reached.  bssb.dev refused to connect
Firefox Error: Unable to connect.  Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at bssb.dev.
```

*it should be noted that both redirect to https://bssb.dev upon failure*

I have pasted the Apache virtual-hosts and system HOSTS file below for reference.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.

#### Apache httpd-vhosts.conf

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName bssb.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/users/ian/documents/mywebprojects/bssb"
    <Directory  "c:/users/ian/documents/mywebprojects/bssb/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName bssb.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/users/ian/documents/mywebprojects/bssb"
    <Directory  "c:/users/ian/documents/mywebprojects/bssb/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

#### System HOSTS file

```
#
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1   bssb.dev
::1 bssb.dev
```

#### Other Details:

```
OS: Windows 8.1 (unfortunately)
Firefox v60.0.2 (64-bit)
Chrome v66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)
IE v11.0.9600.19003
WAMPsever v3.1.3 (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS without explicit port number means port 443. Add virtual host for port 443.

Comment: Thanks for your reply mentallurg.  This is my first experience with Apache, so would you be able to provide more detail on how to add a virtual port?  Thank you.

Comment: There is no virtual port. There is virtual HOST. do it just as you did, but instead of port 80 use port 443.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification.  I created a replica virtual host using port 443 and updated the vhosts.conf file in my original post.  However, when I load localhost I am showing the following error: _bssb.dev:443 not a listen port_.  When I try to add 443 as a listening port for Apache through WAMP, I receive that error that the port is not valid, already used, or is the default port